# UIStackView content hugging is not working as expected in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I have two vertical `StackView` nested in horizontal `StackView`. 
 For the first one:

```
titlesView.axis = .vertical
titlesView.distribution = .fill
titlesView.alignment = .leading
```

And the second one:

```
checkView.axis = .vertical
checkView.distribution = .fil
checkView.alignment = .center
```

and for holderStackView(root)

```
    holderStackView.axis = .horizontal
    holderStackView.alignment = .center
    holderStackView.distribution = .fill


    holderStackView.addArrangedSubview(titlesView)
    holderStackView.addArrangedSubview(checkView)


    titlesView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    checkView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

I expect the titlesView must fill the StackView, but the checkView StackView fills the holderStackView stack view.

if I set alignment for both of them `center` or `leading`, then it works as expected and the first one grows.

Expectation:

[image]

Reality:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

It happens only in the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell`, see the minimal example below:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.87, green:0.87, blue:0.87, alpha:1.00)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.00)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return MedicationHomeCell()
    }
}
```

```
class MedicationHomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    let holderStackView = UIStackView()
    let checkView = UIStackView()
    let titlesView = UIStackView()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        layoutViews()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutViews()
    }

    func layoutViews() {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .white

        self.contentView.addSubview(holderStackView)
        holderStackView.addArrangedSubview(titlesView)
        holderStackView.addArrangedSubview(checkView)

        titlesView.axis = .vertical
        titlesView.distribution = .fill
        titlesView.alignment = .leading

        checkView.axis = .vertical
        checkView.distribution = .fill
        checkView.alignment = .center

        holderStackView.axis = .horizontal
        holderStackView.alignment = .center
        holderStackView.distribution = .fill


        titlesView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        checkView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

        holderStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            holderStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor),
            holderStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor),
            holderStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
            holderStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor)
            ])


        for index in 0..<2 {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "Label \(index)"
            label.backgroundColor = .red
            titlesView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }

        for index in 0..<2 {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "Text \(index)"
            label.backgroundColor = .green
            checkView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set the proper content hugging (horizontal)? +I would prefer to see the code

Comment: @MilanNosáľ , I edit and add some code

Comment: I've updated your code to make it easier to try it out for others. I'm having the same issue and as of right now I have no idea why is it behaving like this.

Comment: Did you find the answer ? I have the same problem, I can't explain

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 13):

UIStackViews don't seem to respect the content hugging and resistance compression properties. Instead, set these properties on each arranged subview.

For nested stack views, you may need to drill down to their non-stack arranged subviews, and set the properties there.